# Games keep crashing due to errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

Story: laptop crashes at minor games after playing them for an X amount of minutes. PC has been sent to
repair before which only helped for a few months without the replacement of parts. The error then returned which has been unsolved.

```
error: LiveKernelEvent 141 / A problem with the hardware caused windows not to function properly
error: Display driver nvlddmkm is unresponsive and is required.
```

#### Possible Causes

Corrupt windows / Windows not shutdown correctly
Failed windows update /

#### Attempted Solutions

- None of these resolved the issue.
- Reverting PC back to before the error took place.
- Reinstalling all the graphic drivers manually and automatically.
- Uninstalling the windows update
- Factory reset the PC.
- sfc/scannow: results do not show anything harmful.
- stress test: does not overheat my laptop.

The laptop has not been overclocked and overheating is not an issue.

Specs:

- Windows 10 home 64 bits (10.0, build 19041)
- GPU Nvidia geforce GTX 1060 6GB VRAM
- CPU Intel core I7-8750H 2.20GHZ
- BIOS v1.26
- 16GB RAM
- Predator PH317-52

Comment: Are you saying you get Windows bughcheck 141 - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x141---video-engine-timeout-detected.  If so, a link to a minidump would be the minimum requirement,  See if there is anything under \windows\minidump\ Given the short description, it's not clear if it is typically caused by a hardware issue with the graphics card but that is a possibility.

Comment: @HelpingHand There is no minidump file generated in the crashing progress of the game, no BSOD is being shown when crashing.